# One-liner to build dict without repeating prefix

Tags: python

I have the prefix `FOOBAR_` and three parameters `P1`, `P2`, and `P3`.

How can I build a dict like the above without repeating the prefix three times?

```
params = {
    "P1": os.environ["FOOBAR_P1"],
    "P2": os.environ["FOOBAR_P2"],
    "P3": os.environ["FOOBAR_P3"],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary comprehension

```
>>> import re
>>> params = {key:os.environ[f"FOOBAR_{key}"] for key in ("P1", "P2", "P3")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary comprehension:

```
params = {item: os.environ["FOOBAR_" + item] for item in ["P1", "P2", "P3"]}
```